# Is a physical lapel pin awarded for FAA Safety Wings?

Tags: ppl, faa-wings-program

I have recently got my PPL, and started the FAA Safety Wings program. After completion of each phase, are we awarded a physical lapel pin?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the FAA currently offers a lapel pin at the completion of each phase of the [WINGS program](https://www.faasafety.gov/).

This "reward" is not automatically awarded or delivered, the WINGS participant must request it. Upon completion of each of a phase, for example Basic, Advanced, or Master, the FAA Safety Team will include the following notice:

> If you have not already done so, I encourage you to go to your My WINGS page at FAASafety.gov and claim your Team Member Reward -- a beautiful set of wings for your lapel.

The pins are sponsored and distributed by AVEMCO, in [partnership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilot_Proficiency_Award_Program) with the FAA.

The pins are available in at least three finishes: bronze, silver, and gold, and a special [sea-plane version](https://www.faasafety.gov/onlinehelp/default.aspx?page=/wings/pub/default.aspx) is apparently available.

[image]
<sup>Source: own work</sup>

Comment: Beautiful!!! I just made the request and waiting for my lapel pin.... Thanks for the information.