# How long to receive FAA wings lapel pin?

Tags: faa, pilot-certification, faa-wings-program

Did anyone request FAA wings lapel pin? If yes, how much time do they take to ship and receive? Do you know if I requested all three phases at once will I get three or just one pin?

Comment: Related: [Is a physical lapel pin awarded for FAA Safety Wings?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/40834/is-a-physical-lapel-pin-awarded-for-faa-safety-wings)

Comment: From deleted comments somewhere else on this website, it seems that it can take several months before they arrive.

Answer (score 1):

I requested all three FAAST WING lapel pins around, but not at, the same time. I think the first two pins were at the same time. It took over three months to receive the first one. When I enquired about the others, I was told that Avemco Insurance (the sponsor of the awards program) orders them in bulk. They ship out the awards only when they have them in stock. So, your experience my vary depending on Avemco’s ordering cycle.